# Why did all my item frames turn to detached entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On the latest snapshot (14w04b), my giant map made of smaller maps and item frames fell off the wall:

[image: Floating entities]

This is happening to all item frames across the map.

What is causing this, and how do I prevent it from happening again? (Also, these all turned to stone entities when I reloaded the save).

Comment: Just going to throw in a "maybe" here. What version of Minecraft was the map originally built on? If you switched to a prerelease, I am thinking that something went wrong in that transition.

Comment: It could be that the frames are rendered first and have no block. The walls are rendered second, but the frames have already fallen.

Answer (score 4):

There was a bug in a recent pre-release that caused item frames to fall off.

I'd highly recommend that you do not use your normal world when testing pre-release versions. Use a temporary world for that purpose, as it is likely that bugs like this will creep in from time to time, some more severe than others.